# HTTPS encryption and internet proxy

Tags: tls, http, proxy, internet-explorer

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Please tell me, and I'll delete it.

I want to modify a Word document hosted on my OneDrive account. I see that it is using a SSL connection with a valid certificate (https://).

I'm asking, if there is a proxy on my network (I think, there isn't), and I read an **encrypted** Microsoft Word document, could anyone read it on my browser cache or on that hypothetical proxy?

Comment: Hi - as Shadur mentioned, this is currently very unclear, and very wide assumptions have had to be made. Can you edit to give some more detail so that Shadur and others can give a full answer. Then we can reopen.

Comment: Be useful to unhold this as I think it can be answered as is.

Comment: There *could* be a proxy and it is *possible* that it might allow access to the document. You could ask this in SuperUser instead. The issue is whether your PC is issued to you by an IT department? If so, it is possible that they have installed an intermediary trusted certificate that allows the proxy to perform a "man in the middle" attack on your connections. This is a **very common** enterprise configuration. There *may* be ways of detecting this but it depends heavily on the configuration of your PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use internet explorer myself, and without knowing what kind of proxy your network is using I can only give the vaguest of answers, but here goes:

- If your network contains a proxy **and** your browser is configured to use said proxy for https traffic, then anyone with admin access to the machine said proxy is running on can theoretically reconfigure the proxy to provide them with a copy of any traffic going through it.
- Furthermore, if your connection **to** the proxy is unencrypted, then anyone with admin access to the network hardware (switches, routers) can use packet capture software like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to intercept and read your traffic.
- Finally, if someone who isn't you has admin access to your computer, or if your computer and/or browser have been compromised by malware, they might in theory be able to read your browser cache and reconstruct your document from it.

**TL;DR** You haven't given us nearly enough information to answer your question in anything but the broadest of terms. The answer is "theoretically, yes", but the vagueness of the question renders it as useless as the same answer would be if I were to ask "If I cross the street, could I get hit by a car?" -- it's certainly possible but without context there's no way to estimate likelihood.